# What is the proper way to handle strings : Java client & C++ server

Tags: java, c++, string, networking, tcp

I'm writing a C++ server/client application (TCP) that is working fine but I will soon have to write a Java client which obviously has to be compatible with the C++ server it connects to.

As for now, when the server or client receives strings (text), it loops through the bits till a '\0' is found, which marks the end of the string ...

Here's the question : is it still a good practice to handle strings that way when communicating over Java/C++ rather than C++/C++ ?

Comment: one thing to remember: Java strings use UTF-8 encoding by default so if your C++ equivalent uses encoding different than ASCII or UTF-8 you might be forced to explicitly specify encoding when reading strings in Java

Comment: @mantrid Java's default encoding is platform specific. You should *always* specify an encoding when converting bytes to strings in Java.

Comment: @mantrid Java (like C#) uses UTF-16 IIRC. But [UTF-8 is better](http://utf8everywhere.org/) anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one thing you should read about: Encodings. Basically, the same sequence of bytes can be interpreted in different ways. As long as you pass things around in C++ or Java, things will agree on their meaning, but when using the net (i.e. a byte stream) you must make up your mind. If in doubt, read about and use UTF-8.

Comment: I knew about encodings as I had to deal with them when I used to code some websites but I'm fairly new to the network programming. Either way, I'll look into it if it solves my initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) or [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org) instead of rolling your own protocol.

Comment: Good answer but I'm already aware of these (Boost libray as well) and would gladly use them if I actually could. It's a requirement of my project not to use any library.